# WebMethod is not active/visible?

Tags: c#, web-services, webmethod

Ok I had one WebMethod in my web service which is working fine.
Then I wanted to add another one where I want to send whole object but when I trying to call this method from Windows Form its says method missing?

WebService code:

```
{ 
[WebMethod]
public int getNumber(int n)
    {
        return n * n * 100;

    }

[WebMethod]
public string GetValues(string value)
        {

            return "OK";
        }
    }
```

Client code:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
localhost.Service1 service2 = new localhost.Service1();
            metadata detective = new metadata();
            detective.CrimeID = txtCrimeID.Text;
            detective.InvestigatorID = txtInvestID.Text;
            detective.DataArtefactID = txtDataID.Text;

            service2.  **<== when I type here GetValues = "Menu.localhost.Service1 does not contain definition for GetValues"** 
}
```

But if straight after "service2." i will start typing get, then method getNumber will be displayed as a possible choice. I dont uderstand Why one method is working fine but another one looks like not exist?

Comment: Did you try updating the reference in your winforms app?

Comment: I tried uploading references and nothing. I removed webservice ref and added again. It is working now but it is localhost.Service1SoapClient instead of localhost.Service1 . why?

Comment: You have a choice of what to name the reference when you add it in the wizard.

Comment: It's probably because you switched from a Web Reference (old) to a Service Reference ("new" for the past 5 years).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After modifying the webservice, the changes will not propogate to your winforms application until you update the reference to it.  The available methods are stored in meta-data for the service when the reference is created.

Update your service reference.

Comment: FYI, also, make sure that the updated service is actually running. You can't get metadata from a service that's not running, at least, not by using the service's URL.